# question about merge algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

hi i have question i know that this question is somehow nonsense but  let see i have code to merge two  sorted array  in a one sorted array here is  code in java

```
public class Merge {

    public static void main(String[]args){

       int a[]=new int[]{7,14,23,30,35,40};
       int b[]=new int[]{5,8,9,11,50,67,81};
       int c[]=new int[a.length+b.length];
       int al=0;
       int bl=0;
       int cl=0;

       while (al<a.length && bl<b.length)              
          if (a[al]<b[bl])
              c[cl++]=a[al++];   
          else  
              c[cl++]=b[bl++];


       while (al<a.length)
          c[cl++]=a[al++];

       while (bl<b.length)
          c[cl++]=b[bl++];

       for (int j=0;j<c.length;j++){
          System.out.println(c[j]);
       }


    }
}
```

question is why does not work if we write here {} brackets

```
while (al<a.length && bl<b.length){
}
```

?

Comment: Pasting your code in a code block would have been oh so nice!

Comment: You should really take more care when posting questions, because this is unreadable. Click on Edit, select your code, then click on the 101010 button, and indent everything properly.

Comment: what is your question? it is not clear.

Comment: Voting to close -- no question here.

Comment: @ closers: there *is* a question here, but admittedly it requires far too much effort to work out right now. Let asker finish his edits and it should become clearer.

Comment: Post the code with the brackets also. It should be easier to understand your question if we compare both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my guess is correct, your question is......why the following code doesn't work?

```
while (al<a.length && bl<b.length)
{ //<-- bracket here

    if (a[al]<b[bl])
      c[cl++]=a[al++];


     else  
     c[cl++]=b[bl++];


    while (al<a.length)
      c[cl++]=a[al++];

    while (bl<b.length)
     c[cl++]=b[bl++];
} //<--- Bracket here
```

If that is the case,

```
while (al<a.length && bl<b.length)
```

would fail after first iteration.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where you put the brackets, your current code is equivalent to:

```
while (al<a.length && bl<b.length) {
    if (a[al]<b[bl]) {
       c[cl++]=a[al++];
    } else {
       c[cl++]=b[bl++];
    }
}
```

If you put the brackets in any other place you will change the semantics of the code.

Comment: @davit and you inserted your brackets at this position? Or anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble with the Merge Sort Algorithm, please check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) Wiki Article.
Also, when posting code it would be nice to give variables a more descriptive name, as well as adding braces (`{ }`) to your `while` and `if` statements

Answer (score 1):

One good advice: **always** surround all logical blocks of code with curly braces:

```
if (expression) { 
   //some code 
}

if (expression) {
   //one line of code
} else {
   //another line
}

while (conditionIsTrue) {
   //just 1 line here but surrounded with curly braces 
}
```

It'll help you avoid numerous not-obvious mistakes in all C-style languages.

How those mistakes can ever appear if you understand that only one line should be in block and you omit braces consciously to make code more readable? Very simple! Just imagine the code:

```
if (a > b) 
   result = a;
```

For the first look it's more elegant then

```
if (a > b) {
   result = a;
}
```

or even

```
if (a > b)
{
   result = a;
}
```

But now let's suppose you want to add some debug info to your code:

```
if (a > b)
   System.out.println ("a > b, we're inside if-block");
   result = a;                            //This line is ALWAYS executed
```

As you can see it's really easy to make a mistake. So just don't omit braces and things will be done much easier.